# yii2: Asset bundle does not load assets when I load page with renderPartial method

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have all my CSS and JavaScript files in AppAsset which I load on the layout file. On my login page, I do not want to use the layout so I render the login view file using
    renderPartial()
method. When doing this I have created a new LoginAsset file and used it to register the login view but still my CSS and JS does not load. I have also tried registering the login view using the AppAsset bundle but it too does not load the CSS and JS. Is there anything I am doing wrong? How can I load my assetbundle when using renderPartial on my controller?

Comment: Where you are registering this asset bundle? Seems like in layout, which is not rendered with `renderPartial`.

Comment: Did you try "renderAjax" method?

Comment: I am registering asset bundle in layout but I have tried registering the same asset bundle in the login view too. I have also tried creating a new asset bundle and registering it on the login view page but still it doesn't load.

Comment: Hello Paul, I am new to Yii2 and not quite familiar with "renderAjax" method. Let me read about it.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the tip! It worked after I used renderAjax() method but I do not really know why. Considering "renderAjax" method adds calls of "beginPage(), head(), beginBody(), endBody() and endPage()" I am thinking maybe my login view failed to load the assetbundle as it lacked this. I still do not understand how it works the same as renderPartial and not render as indicated on the documentation. I will be reading more on it.

Answer (score 4):

Hi @Zack your problem is you didn't specified end body and end page locations. 
I was solved my problem add these codes to bottom of my page.

```
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Pavel said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465226/#comment47093768_29465226) you shold use `renderAjax()`. See explanation below.

Output of `renderPartial()` is a peace of HTML generated by view without any CSS ans JS:

```
<div class="container">
   <input type="text" id="loginform-username" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[username]">
   <input type="password" id="loginform-password" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[password]">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="login-button">Log in</button>
</div>
```

But `renderAjax()` adds CSSs and JSs from all registred **in the view** assets to the output:

```
<link href="/assets/f1759119/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
   <input type="text" id="loginform-username" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[username]">
   <input type="password" id="loginform-password" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[password]">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="login-button">Log in</button>
</div>
<style>
   ...
</style>
<script>
   ...
</script>
<script src="/assets/13aa7b5d/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/302a2946/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/302a2946/yii.activeForm.js"></script>
```

PS. I think the right way is to create separate layout for login form and use usual `render()` method.